# Can I use with clause while opening a CURSOR

Tags: oracle

Can I use WITH clause while using cursor

```
OPEN CURSOR_NAME FOR 
WITH view1 as (Select v_name from tablename),
view2 as (Select p_name from tablename2)
Select * from view1, view2;
```

Comment: Have you tried? Also, consider switching to ANSI join syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible to use `with` clause in cursor. Check the below example.

```
DECLARE
   l_cur sys_refcursor;
   l_val VARCHAR2 (1000);
BEGIN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE;

   OPEN l_cur FOR
      WITH tab AS
           (SELECT 'hello'
              FROM DUAL)
      SELECT *
        FROM tab;

   FETCH l_cur
    INTO l_val;

   CLOSE l_cur;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_val);
END;
```

Output: `hello`